# Optimizing an Oracle query by using a subquery to limit the rows on which and expensive filter is applied

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have an Oracle query that returns one or zero rows, from a complex query containing lots of joins and filters. I was tasked with optimizing that query, so that it can execute faster.

I have identified that a big factor in the query's bad performance is a call to a function from the WHERE clause. The simplified query looks like this:

```sql
select id, col1, col2, IS_VALID(id) as VALIDITY_CHECK
FROM table1,
-- a few joins...
WHERE IS_VALID(id) == 'TRUE'
-- AND other filters....
```

Commenting the call to IS_VALID in the WHERE clause improves performance greatly. I think I can undestand why: in the WHERE clause, the function has to be called once for every line in the table, whereas the one present in the SELECT clause will be called once for every row in the result set (so never more than for one row, even with the function call commented in the WHERE clause)

In order to improve this, I was thinking of putting my query in a FROM subquery, without the call in the WHERE clause, and then put a filter on VALIDITY_CHECK in the parent query, so that the filter only applies on the small set of pre-filtered rows. It looks like this:

```sql
select * FROM (
  select id, col1, col2, IS_VALID(id) as VALIDITY_CHECK
  FROM table1,
  -- a few joins...
  WHERE -- other filters...
)
WHERE VALIDITY_CHECK='TRUE'
```

However, that didn't work. In fact, it looks like the compiler has optimized my query to put everything back in a single query: when I ask for the query plans, the plan hash values are the exact same for both queries!

Did I maybe understand something wrong? What do I need to do to tell Oracle to execute that filter on the results of the first query?

Comment: @MT0, that is not a duplicate of the question you pointed to. That question had to do with calls for every object member, which is a byproduct of OO types in Oracle SQL. This OP is dealing with the performance impact of a scalar function call.

Comment: @PaulW The solution is to materialize the query (you state it in the final part of your answer and the OP states that that was the solution in a comment). The solution in the duplicates is also to materialize the query and all the linked duplicates suggest adding the (undocumented) `/*+ materialize */` or the `/*+ no_merge */` hint or using `ROWNUM` to perform the same effect. They are all effectively the same problem that the SQL engine is rewriting the query and pushing the function call into the outer query when it needs to be materialized. So I'll disagree; the question is a duplicate.

Comment: @MT0, the other post was about reducing the # of function calls. This post turned out to be about how the additional predicate changed the rest of the plan and made it suboptimal. The materialize hint here by preventing predicate pushdown allowed the rest of the query logic to use the plan it otherwise would have without the additional predicate. If OP was familiar with hinting join order and method, hints would have been an easier solution. The solution that worked for OP did not reduce the # of calls or save time on those calls. It allowed for a better join order. Same solution, diff issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rewritten version is the same thing under the covers, as you've discovered.

Most likely the cost of executing that function for every single row in the table at query time is too high. You do however have the option of pre-executing the function once and storing its result so that it doesn't need to be re-executed with each query. To do this, try creating a *function-based index*:

```
create index i_table1_validity on table1 (is_valid(id));
```

You may have to recompile the `is_valid` function with the `deterministic` clause in order to create the index, assuming it is in fact deterministic (always returns the same value for a given input).

Then you can query it simply:

```
WHERE IS_VALID(id) = 'TRUE'
```

The downside is of course to leverage using the stored result in the index, your query has to *use* the index. If you are going after a significant portion of rows in the table, that is not an optimal access path. A full table scan is better. If that's the case, you may want to either enable the Result Cache (which has potential problems of its own), or denormalize by adding a column to the table and populating it with `is_valid(id)` at insert-time. Or, if you can't mess with the main table, creating and maintaining a 1:1 sister table with this information (either via scheduled refresh or trigger) and joining to it in your queries.

Also, consider whether or not you need to do tuning within the `is_valid` function itself. It could be that you have a SQL problem inside there and fixing that will make it fast enough that processing it for every row at query time is acceptable.

Finally, and perhaps I should have put this first, your problem may not be with this function at all, but rather with join order and/or join method. Adding or dropping the function as a predicate will certainly change Oracle's optimizer math and could easily cause it to change join order and/or method to something sub-optimal for your data. Examine the execution plans and see if that's the case. If it is, you may be able to fix it simply by hinting the proper join order and methods. If this is out of reach, then try wrapping the existing query in a materialized CTE (Common Table Expression, or "WITH" clause) which will prevent predicate pushdown:

```
WITH data AS (select /*+ materialize */ id, col1, col2
                FROM table1,
                -- a few joins...
                WHERE 1=1
                -- AND other filters....
             )
SELECT id, col1, col2, IS_VALID(id) validity_check
  FROM data
WHERE IS_VALID(id) = 'TRUE'
```

This doesn't reduce the # of calls to that function or the expense of calling it, but it may prevent the change in plan if that's what the real problem is.

Comment: The function cannot be deterministic, as its results depends on external factors. I've been trying to understand more deeply the execution plan (removing the condition does change the nested loops organization at the start of the plan), but I feel that I'm far from being able to fully understand it yet... Would you say that my idea of running the predicate on another queries results is not possible, or that it's not the best idea compared to alternatives ?

Comment: @Shtong, You would need to fix the plan with hints. Or, you can wrap the whole thing in a materialized CTE to prevent predicate push-down and see how that works for you. I'll update my answer with this so you can give it a try.

Comment: @Shtong, updated again.

Comment: The `materialize` trick seems to work here, but I'll try to see if hints could be a better supported option. Thanks for your help.